# Многофайловые проекты C++

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++

хочу окончательно разобраться с многофайловыми проектами. Если у меня есть, скажем, три *.h файла, которые имеют следующий вид:

```
//h1.h
#pragma once
#ifndef _H1_H_
#define _H1_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class H1 
{
};
#endif
```

И я хочу их подключить к файлу main.cpp

```
#include "H1.h"
#include "H2.h"
#include "H2.h"

int main()
{

}
```

1. Будет ли в таком случае в файл main.cpp подставлено по три isotream-а, string-а, vector-а?
2. Правильно ли вообще в *.h файлы подключать какие-либо библиотеки или лучше это делать в файлах *.cpp (в котором подключается соответствующий *.h файл)?
3. Если ответ на первый вопрос является отрицательным, то в каком случае произойдет множественное подключение?
4. Правильно ли я понимаю, что #pragma работает только в Visual studio и поэтому дополнительно используются средства условной компиляции?
   Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам стоит задать 4 отдельных вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно оставить только одно из двух: (лучше первое)

- `#pragma once`
- ```
  #ifndef _H1_H_
  #define _H1_H_
  ...
  #endif
  ```

Это не ошибка, а просто бессмысленная избыточность.

Также стоит заметить, что идентификаторы, начинающиеся с `_`, за которым следует заглавная буква, [зарезервированы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), также как и любые идентификакторы, содержащие `__`. Так что если решите оставить второй варинат, вам стоит сменить `_H1_H_` на другое название.

> Будет ли в таком случае в файл main.cpp подставлено по три isotream-а, string-а, vector-а?

Нет, не беспокойтесь об этом. В каждом из этих файлов стоит свой scope guard (т.е. одна из двух вещей, написанных выше). Ну и плюс, их все дополниельно прикрывает еще и ваш собственный scope guard.

> Правильно ли вообще в *.h файлы подключать какие-либо библиотеки

Да, это правильно. В общем случае каждый `.h` должен быть самодостаточен, для его использования не должно быть нужно подключать дополнительные хедеры.

И наоборот, если хедер не использует библиотеку, не надо ее подключать. Если библиотека нужна только в `.cpp`, но не в `.h`, подключайте ее в `.cpp`.

> Если ответ на первый вопрос является отрицательным, то в каком случае произойдет множественное подключение?

Его можно получить, если вы пишете свои хедеры без scope guard-ов, и в одном .cpp включаете их больше одного раза (возможно не напрямую, а через другие хедеры).

На стандартных хедерах эту ошибку получить невозможно, потому что в них scope guard-ы уже стоят.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что #pragma работает только в Visual studio

Хотя `#pragma once` не входит в стандарт С++, она работает на всех нормальных (и некоторых ненормальных) компиляторах. Используйте смело.

Comment: про стражи включения: ты же хотел сказать «лучше второе», не?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Дописал.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Про неиспользуемые хедеры дописал.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет, там же стоят аж целых два `include-guard`
2. Теоретически, лучше всего в `*.h` помещать как можно меньше деклараций, а в `*.cpp` - как можно больше. Потому что при компиляции `*.h` может куда-то включиться и "раздуть" пространство имен лишними декларациями
3. Множественное включение приведет к дублированию деклараций и ошибке сборки, его не нужно допускать, а для этого во всех без исключения хидерах ставят include-guards
4. Если у вас очень древний или необычный компилятор. GCC/Clang свежих версий все прекрасно понимают.

Comment: Минусующие приглашаются в коментарии с аргументами

Comment: Ок. Минус за второй и третий пункт: Будучи верными по сути, они не являются ответами на заданные вопросы. Просто потому, что ушли от них несколько в сторону.

Comment: Хорошо, а то я опасался, что допускил фактические ошибки. На вопрос "верно ли я интерпретировал" может ответить нам только автор, так что я отвечал в рамках своей интерпретации вопроса, которая может быть и не верна, но при этом, может оказаться для кого-то полезной.

Comment: @gdb, ни на секунду не сомневался в ее полезности. Просто мне показалось, что разница между "Когда может возникнуть" и "Чем опасно" множественное наследование - достаточно заметна. Но, опять же, это лишь моя интерпретация вопроса и ответа :)